# Prove that $\oint_C z^n dz = 0$ for any closed curve $C$ on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently working on line integrals on complex plane and I want to prove the following statement.

> Prove that $\oint_C z^n dz = 0$ for any closed curve $C$ on
>   $\mathbb{C}$ when $n \ge 0, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

My testbook, which is "*Joseph Bak's complex analysis*" has a theorem(Closed Curve Theorem, 4.16 on textbook) that whenever $C$ is a smooth closed curve and $f$ is entire,  $\oint_C f(z) dz = 0$ holds because by Integral Theorem, there is an entire function such that $f(z) = F'(z)$.
But my task now is to show that this holds for any closed curve $C$(maybe even not simple? but not sure if $\oint_C f(z) dz = 0$ holds even in that case) and I don't know how to approach this problem. Can you give me some hint regarding this matter?

Comment: This can't be true for _any_ closed curve, because in general that integral will be undefined.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can you give a counter example that make this integral not defiend?

Comment: Where did you find this task and how is the integral defined for a closed curve?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I got this task for complex analysis class practice problem, and it was printed. TAs may have forgotten to put 'smooth' but I thought this should be proved this way. And I though the integral can be defined as usual as in the smooth curve case. Is it not the case? Is line integral defined only for the smooth and simple curve?

Comment: The definition is $\int_C f(z)dz=\int_a^{b} f(\gamma (t)) \gamma '(t) dt$ for a piece-wise smooth curve $\gamma $ defined on $[a,b]$. There is no definition of this integral without any smoothness.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think it is possible to define it without imposing (piecewise) smoothness on $\gamma$ by using the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, something along the lines of $\int_Cf(z)\ dz:=\int_{a}^{b}f\ d\gamma$. I think Conway's book does it this way.

Comment: I don't think your Riemann Steiltje's integral would exist whenever $\gamma $ and $f$ are continuous. What additional conditions are you imposing? @Teddy38

Comment: @Teddy38 Yes, you can define the integral that way. Except that only works if $C$ is _rectifiable_.

Comment: @Teddy38 Conway assumes that $\gamma $ is of bounded variation. This implies, in particular, that it is differentable a..e. So Conway does not deal with an arbitrary contnuous curve.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah well, at least it takes the definition from piecewise smooth to a.e. smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ultimately depends on the definition of line-integral one gives (Terence Tao wrote a beautiful set of notes on complex analysis, and one of those is dedicated precisely to this topic: see his blog [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/246a-notes-2-complex-integration/#more-9372)). With the definition Bak gives, this result is wrong, as one does not know how to give meaning to the expression $\int{\gamma}f$ if $\gamma$ is not smooth. This may seem a technicality, but once you discover pathological curves such as 
the [Peano' curve](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve), or [Osgood' curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve), it becomes clear that this is a subject that we need to approach with caution.

However, there are some generalizations: the more common one is to define the line-integral from the basis, with something similar to Riemann sums (here $\mathcal{P}$ is a partition of the interval $[0,1]$, i.e. a sequence of numbers $t_0\le t^*_0\le t_1\dots\le t_n:[t_0,t_1]\cup\dots\cup [t_{n-1}, t_n]=[0,1]$ and $\text{mesh}(\mathcal{P})$ is defined as $\max_i t_{i+1}-t_i$)

$$\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz:=\lim_{\text{mesh}(\mathcal{P})\to 0}\sum_{\mathcal{P}} f(\gamma(t^*_i))\cdot (\gamma(t_{i+1})-\gamma(t_i))$$

With this definition one is able to easily prove that the integral is meaningful provided that $f$ is continuous and $\gamma$ is a  [rectifiable curve](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Rectifiable_curve) (one can weaken the hypotesis on $f$, but that is not relevant here). Still, this definition  is  not general. As an example, if you take $\gamma(t):=t+it\sin\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)$, even $\int_{\gamma}zdz$ is not well defined, as the limit in the previous equation does not exist (try it yourself: to show that the limit does not exists, you can try to find two different partitions such that, even if the mesh of both of them goes to zero, the difference between the two associated sums grows indefinitely).

The problem, however, can be solved: if we **add** the hypotesis that $f$ is entire, we can define the integral of f to be the same given two homotopic curves (with fixed endpoints). By [Cauchy theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), we know that this definition is well-posed. This allows us to give a general definition even if $\gamma$ is simply supposed to be continuous. The result you are looking for, however, is trivial at this point, since we already used Cauchy's theorem in the definition.

In conclusion, we have 3 different definitions of line-integral:

1. For smooth curves: the statement is wrong, as we do not know how to integrate on general curves
2. For rectifiable curves: the statement is wrong, as we do not know hot to integrate on general curves
3. For continuous curves: the statement is true, but trivial.